Weakly Stationary Process Confusion
Suppose that I sample $2n$ iid normals $A_k, B_k$ with $k=1,...n$, all with mean 0, but $Var(A_k) = Var(B_k)$. Using these, I can build a random time series
$$X(t) := \sum_{k=1}^n (A_k + iB_k) e^{i\lambda_kt} + (A_k - iB_k) e^{-i\lambda_kt},$$ where $0 < \lambda_k$ is some sequence of fixed (nonrandom) $n$ real numbers.
Now, by construction:

$X(t)$ is real valued.
$E[X(t)] = 0$ for all $t$
$E[X(t)X(t+\tau)] = 4\sum_k Var(A_k) e^{i\lambda_k \tau}$  (for this, write $Z_k = A_k + i B_k$ so there are only 4 terms)

In particular, $X(t)$ is a real valued, weakly stationary sequence.
Next, I can generate some of these with this code:
def make_normal(lambdas, stds, T):
    assert len(stds) == len(lambdas), "Must provide a stddev for each lambda."
    lambdas.sort()
    assert all([l >= 0 for l in lambdas]), "Input lambdas must be nonneg"

    
    Z_real = np.random.normal(scale = stds)
    Z_complex = np.random.normal(scale = stds)
    if lambdas[0] == 0:
        Z_real[0] /= 2
        Z_complex[0] = 0

    Z_real = np.concatenate([Z_real, Z_real])
    Z_complex = np.concatenate([Z_complex, -Z_complex])
    Z = Z_real + 1j*Z_complex

    lambdas = [-l for l in lambdas] + lambdas

    exps = np.exp(np.outer(lambdas, T)*1j)


    return np.matmul(Z, exps)
    
lambdas = [0.1, 1, 2, 5, 10]
stds = [2, 1, 0.7, 0.5, 0.1]
T = [0.1*i for i in range(500)]
X = make_normal(lambdas, stds, T)
assert max(abs(np.imag(X))) < 1e-10, "Something not right with TS... should be real!"
plt.plot(T, np.real(X))


This definitely doesn't "look stationary" by all the heuristics I've seen. So my question is which of these is true:

There is something wrong with my code.
The heuristics I've learned about when a process "looks stationary" is just totally wrong - This time series does not "look stationary" to me, because it seemingly has trends, seasonality, etc. Almost all of the time series I generate with this code have these features.
Something else is totally wrong!

Thanks for your time! :)

After thinking about it, it could be that this is just an example of just how weak weakly stationary processes are. In the simplest case of the example $$X(t) = (A+iB)e^{i\lambda t} + (A-iB)e^{-i\lambda t},$$ the function
$$E[X(t_0)X(t_1)X(t_2)] = 4\bigg((E[A^3] -iE[B^3])e^{i\lambda (t_0+t_1+t_2)} + (E[A^3] + iE[B^3])e^{-i\lambda (t_0+t_1+t_2)}\bigg)$$ is not the same as $E[X(0)X(t_1-t_0)X(t_2-t_0)].$
